# How to take a string, split it into an array and then join it back together

Tags: c#, string

I have some code that will take in a string from console in [0,0,0,0] format. I then want to split it into an array but leave the [] and only take the numbers. How do i do this? This is what i have, i thought i could split it all and remove the brackets after but it doesnt seem to take the brackets and rather just leaves a null space. is there a way to split from index 1 to -1?

```
input = Console.ReadLine();

Char[] splitChars = {'[',',',']'};
List<string> splitString = new List<string>(input.Split(splitChars));

Console.WriteLine("[" + String.Join(",", splitString) + "]");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `string.Split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love using [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) for such tasks, because you can use `Console.WriteLine()` to get the details of a result like so:

[image: LinqPad]

It becomes obvious that you have empty entries, i.e. `""` at the beginning and the end. You want to remove those with the overloaded funtion that takes `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` [[MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-stringsplitoptions)):

```
List<string> splitString = new List<string>(input.Split(splitChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Result:

[image: LinqPad Result]

Comment: Thanks that's perfect, i'll look into that software too, it looks very useful.

Comment: It starts up quickly, doesn't need boilerplate code and the output feature is useful. I really like it for solving smaller problems. Have a nice day and good luck.